# IOS UIViewController adopts UIKeyInput - is it possible to configure the keyboard that shows for it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have setup a viewcontroller to adopt the UIKeyInput so that I can take user input without a displayed textfield. I have a textfield that is atteched as an input accessory view to the keyboard so the user can see the text.

I run into issues with the predictive text. My guess is that the keyboard that shows for the UIViewController shows the text but then when the textfield becomes first responder, it quickly collapses it when autocorrection is set to No on the textfield's keyboard.

Any thoughts on how to access and configure the keyboard for the UIViewController that becomes first responder? I'd like to be able to use the different keyboard types too so its not only a question about the autocorrection.

Answer (score 0):

Also implement [`UITextInputTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits) protocol, with this you can set the properties to give it the desired appearance.