# How to go back when the UITextfield is empty in Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

My question is: When the UITextField is empty, how do I click the "Backspace" button to go to the previous UITextField? I have been struggling trying to do this in my code below?

Second Question: How do I only allow 1 character to get entered in the UITextField?

I am new at Swift code and trying to learn. Any help would be great.

What I am trying to do is have the user be able to type in a code in the 6 UITextFields and be able to click the "Backspace" button on any one of the UITextFields with only allowing the user to enter one number in each UITextField.

[image]

Code Below:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(textfield: UITextField) {
    let text = textfield.text!
    if text.utf16.count == 0 {
        switch textfield {
        case textField2:
            textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            textField1.tintColor = .clear
        case textField3:
            textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            textField2.tintColor = .clear
        case textField4:
            textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField3.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            textField3.tintColor = .clear
        case textField5:
            textField4.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField4.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            textField4.tintColor = .clear
        case textField6:
            textField5.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField5.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            textField5.tintColor = .clear
            textField6.resignFirstResponder()
            textField6.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            textField6.tintColor = .clear
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    else if text.utf16.count == 1 {
        switch textfield {
        case textField1:
            textField1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            textField1.textColor = .white
            textField1.tintColor = .clear
            textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField2.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            textField2.textColor = .white
            textField2.tintColor = .clear
        case textField2:
            textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField3.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            textField3.textColor = .white
            textField3.tintColor = .clear
        case textField3:
            textField4.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField4.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            textField4.textColor = .white
            textField4.tintColor = .clear
        case textField4:
            textField5.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField5.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            textField5.textColor = .white
            textField5.tintColor = .clear
        case textField5:
            textField6.becomeFirstResponder()
            textField6.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            textField6.textColor = .white
            textField6.tintColor = .clear
        case textField6:
            textField6.resignFirstResponder()
        default:
            break

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this is like the third time you've asked this question in the last 24 hours - since SO is a global community, it may take a few days for your question to been by community - the question is, what's wrong with any of the other answers to this same question you've received? You may also want to restrict you question to a single question - as this seems to be causing you issues

Comment: Duplicates of [How can I move to the previous UITextField if the “Backspace” button is pressed and the text field is blank and in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936231/how-can-i-move-to-the-previous-uitextfield-if-the-backspace-button-is-pressed) and [How to move cursor from one text field to another automatically when the user clicks the Delete Button in swift ios programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930852/how-to-move-cursor-from-one-text-field-to-another-automatically-when-the-user-cl)

Comment: Appreciate the advice, and will think about that next time. For the feedback that I have received, it has been helpful but hasn't worked in the above code. I have been stuck on this for two weeks and can't figure out how to solve it. Can you help me out please?

Comment: @BoxHouse I took a crack at this before I went to bed last night, but I can't figure out how to get the delete button to navigate to the prior textfield.  To restrict character count and type of characters a field will accept, you'll want to implement the UITextFieldDelegate method shouldChangeCharactersIn. Here's a repo I threw up that you can take a peek at. shouldChangeCharactersIn. https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/TextFieldDemo

Comment: This is great! I am having the same issue where I can't get the delete button to navigate to the prior textfield.. Did you have any more luck getting it to go to the prior field?

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to point out that I'm still relatively new to iOS and Swift in general, but even with just a few minutes of searching, I was able to find some seeds of ideas which provided me with the suggested solution.

Based on your (improved) question, I believe a different approach is required.  What you really don't want to use a text component.  "Why"?
 I here you ask.  Because they don't actually provide you with the functionality that you want and come with a considerable overhead.

For this, what you really want is more control.  You want to know when a key is pressed and you want to respond to it (I know, sounds like a text component, but) and be notified when more extended functionality occurs, like the delete key is pressed.

After a few minutes of research, some trial and error, I found that the [`UIKeyInput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput) is more along the lines of what you want.

It will tell you when text is inserted and, more importantly, will tell you when <kbd>Delete</kbd> is pressed

The added benefit is, you can filter the input directly. You can take the first character from the `String` and ignore the rest or auto fill the following elements with the remaining text.  You can perform validation (for numerical only content) and what ever else you might want to do

So, I started a really new project, added a `UILabel` to the `UIViewController` in the storyboard, bound it to the source and implemented the `UIKeyInput` protocol as such...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIKeyInput {

    var hasText: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func insertText(_ text: String) {
        print(text)
        label.text = text
    }

    func deleteBackward() {
        print("Delete backward")
    }

}
```

I ran the project and when a key was typed, the label was updated with the new key and when delete was pressed, the `Delete backward` text was printed to console.

Now. You have some choices to make.  To use a single `UIViewController` and (maybe) a series of `UILabel`s and manage interactions within it, so when a key is typed, you present the next label as the input focus (and when delete is pressed, you move back) or do you create a series of `UIControl`s which represent each digit and manage via some delegate call back process.

You may also need to implement the [`UITextInputTraits`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174258/ios-uiviewcontroller-adopts-uikeyinput-is-it-possible-to-configure-the-keyboar?rq=1) protocol, which will allow you to control the keyboard presented

You might also like to have a read through [Responding to Keyboard Events on iOS](https://coderwall.com/p/xuawww/responding-to-keyboard-events-on-ios), [CustomTextInputView.swift](https://gist.github.com/austinzheng/a8563c6babfd61401be3) and [Showing the iOS keyboard without a text input](http://stephengroom.co.uk/uikit/showing-ios-keyboard-without-text-input/) which were just some of the resources I used to hobble this basic example together with.

Comment: is it better to use virtual keyboard on the viewController ? I mean design a numeric pad and use it instead of using the os keyboard

Comment: That’s up to you

Comment: @arash [This](https://github.com/yankodimitrov/SwiftPasscodeLock) is something I used when I was required to provide a pin entry view - wrote my own, but it gave me some ideas

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to try to see if this works in my code. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this extension for your second question:

```
import UIKit

private var maxLengths = [UITextField: Int]()
extension UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
        get {
            guard let length = maxLengths[self] else {
                return Int.max
            }
            return length
        }
        set {
            maxLengths[self] = newValue
            addTarget(
                self,
                action: #selector(limitLength),
                for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged
            )
        }
    }

    @objc func limitLength(textField: UITextField) {
        guard let prospectiveText = textField.text,
            prospectiveText.count > maxLength
            else {
                return
        }

        let selection = selectedTextRange
        let maxCharIndex = prospectiveText.index(prospectiveText.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
        text = prospectiveText.substring(to: maxCharIndex)
        selectedTextRange = selection
    }
}
```

when you add this extension to your project you can see an extra attribute in "Attribute Inspector" tab and you can set the max length of `UITextField`.

Comment: and I couldn't find answer for your first question since you asked it for first time.